# Two different formulations of the Bott–Samelson resolution

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, geometric-representation-theory

There seem to be two formulations of the Bott–Samelson resolution flowing around. For concreteness, let $ G = \mathrm{GL}_{n} ( \mathbb{C} ) $ with the Borel subgroup $ B \subset G $ of upper triangular matrices, and denote by $ P_i \subset G $ the $i$th parabolic. Fix a reduced expression $ w = s_{i_1} \cdots s_{i_k} $.

Denoting by $ \times^B $ the cross product modulo the diagonal $ B $-action, the first formulation says that multiplication defines a map
$$
P_{i_1} \times^B \dotsb \times^B P_{i_k}
\xrightarrow{\textrm{mult}}
\overline{BwB}
\subset
G
$$
which is a resolution of singularities since it restricts to an isomorphism of open subsets
$$
(P_{i_1}-B) \times^B \dotsb \times^B (P_{i_k}-B)
\xrightarrow{\;\sim\;}
BwB
.
$$

On the other hand, we can consider the flag variety $ G / B $ and define a map
$$
G/B \times_{G/P_{i_1}}\dotsb \times_{G/P_{i_k}} G/B
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{first\times last}}
\overline{ G ( wB , B ) }
\subset
G/B\times G/B
$$
which drops all coordinates except the first and last one. This is also a resolution of singularities since it restricts to an isomorphism of open subsets
$$
\bigl\{\,
( g_0 B , \dotsc , g_nB ) \bigm|
g_i B \neq g_{i+1} B \text{ for all $i$}
\,\bigr\}
\xrightarrow{\;\sim\;}
G(wB,B).
$$

We note that the RHSs of these maps differ by $ B \backslash G / B \cong (G/B \times G/B)/G $, so the LHSs should differ the same way.
For now, let us ignore all stack-related stuff and just pretend that these are honest quotient spaces.

The varieties $ G / P_i $ can be thought of as the varieties of partial flags $ 0 = V_0 \subset V_1 \subset \dotsb \subset V_{i-1} \subset V_{i+1} \subset\dotsb\subset V_n = \mathbb{C}^{n} $ where $ \dim (V_j / V_k) = j - k $. Thus an element in the fibre product $ G/B \times_{ G / P_{i} } G/B $ is of the form $ (gpB,gB) $ for some $ p \in P_i $.
Therefore, in passing from one formulation to the other, it is natural to try to write a map like
\begin{align*}
B\backslash P_{i_1} \times^B \dotsb \times^B P_{i_k}/B
& \longrightarrow
\bigl( G/B \times_{G/P_{i_1}}\dotsb \times_{G/P_{i_k}} G/B \bigr)/G \\
(p_1 , \dotsc , p_k )
& \longmapsto
\bigl(
p_1 \dotsm p_k B , p_2 \dotsm p_k B , \dotsc, p_k B , B
\bigr)
.
\end{align*}
However, **how can this map be well-defined**? Any $ (p_1 , \dotsc , p_k ) $ is equivalent to $ (p_1 , \dotsc , p_i b^{-1} , b p_{i-1} , \dotsc , p_k ) $,
but I don’t see how $ ( p_1 \dotsm p_k B , p_2 \dotsm p_k B , \dotsc, p_k B , B ) $ can be equivalent to $ ( p_1 \dotsm p_k B , p_2 \dotsm p_k B , \dotsc , b p_{i-1} \dotsm p_{k} B, \dotsc, p_k B , B ) $. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does "the $i$th parabolic" mean "the $i$th maximal parabolic", hence presumably the block upper triangular matrices of shape $(i, n - i)$?  Also, what does $G(w B, B)$ mean?

Comment: I don’t know the term “shape $(i,n-i)$.” By the $i$th parabolic, I mean the subgroup of matrices which are almost upper triangular, except that they may be non-zero in the $(i+1,i)$th entry. Is that the same as what you are saying? The notation $G(wB,B)$ means the $G$-orbit containing the element $(wB,B) \in G/B \times G/B$. The $G$-action is the natural left, diagonal action on $G/B \times G/B$.

Comment: Ah, you are [describing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378660/two-different-formulations-of-the-bott-samelson-resolution#comment960956_378660) a *minimal* parabolic, not the maximal parabolic that I guessed (where we allow non-zero entries below the diagonal if both coordinates are at most, or if both coordinates are bigger than, $i$).  For example, I would say your minimal parabolic has shape $(1^{i - 1}, 2, 1^{n - i - 1})$.

Comment: As to $G(w B, B)$, sorry about misunderstanding the notation!  I somehow totally missed that it was just the orbit under a group action, and read it instead (nonsensically) as a function $G$ of two arguments.  Does your big $\times^B$ product mean that we identify $(g_1, \dotsc, g_k)$ with $(g_1, \dotsc, g_i b, b^{-1}g_{i + 1}, \dotsc, g_k)$ for all $i$ and $B$?  (Your later discussion makes it seem so, but that's not what I'm used to calling "the diagonal action"—for example, it's not really a single action of $B$!)

Comment: Anyway, if I understand correctly, I think it's just a matter of acting on the correct side:  note that the element you write doesn't lie in $G/B \times_{G/P_{i_1}} \dotsb \times_{G/P_{i_k}} G/B$, *and* that that set doesn't naturally admit a right $G$-action.  Why not $p \mapsto (B, p_1 B, \dotsc, p_1\dotsm p_k B) \in G\backslash(G/B \times_{G/P_{i_1}} \times \dotsb \times_{G/P_{i_k}} G/B)$?

Comment: @Gaussler: I found the proof of Lemma 3.2.1 in "On the relation between intersection cohomology and representation theory in positive characteristic" by W. Soergel helpful. I might be missing something, but the line identifying $Y$ (Soergel's notation) with a fibre product seems to be what you want.

Comment: @LSpice You are right, I wrote the map wrongly (see my answer where I credit you). As for left and right actions of $G$, I was aware that it is a left action. I tend to use the notation $X/G$ even when the action is a left action, as I don’t like the look of $G\backslash X$. I guess it is a bit sloppy.

Comment: @LSpice, and yes, by diagonal $B$-action, I mean what you write. Again, I’m sometimes sloppy when I think what I really mean is clear, but as you point out, it might not be as clear after all. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being stupid. Of course, as @LSpice also [remarks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378660/two-different-formulations-of-the-bott-samelson-resolution#comment960977_378660), the real map is
\begin{align*}
B\backslash P_{i_1} \times^B \dotsb \times^B P_{i_k}/B
& \longrightarrow
\bigl( G/B \times_{G/P_{i_1}}\dotsb \times_{G/P_{i_k}} G/B \bigr)/G \\
(p_1 , \dotsc , p_k )
& \longmapsto
\bigl(
B , p_1 B , p_1 p_2 B , \dotsc, p_1 \dotsm p_k B
\bigr)
.
\end{align*}

Comment: @LSpice Of course. Corrected now. Thanks. :-)